# I'm not able to allocate the sums of integers in a list using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to give a general score to different sentences, some words have different values and I need a general score for each of the sentences:

```
sentences = ['This is so awesome , fr!', 'Ngl Im bad', 'awesome ! still bad tho' ] 
values = {'awesome' : 4, 'bad' : -1 }
```

This is the for loop I used to get the sentences split:

```
split = [] 
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    split.append(sentences[i].lower().split(' '))
```

so far so good, but now I cannot get the general score of each of the sentences in a list, I've tried using for loops but never got the desired output, this was my first attempt:

```
scores = [0,0,0]

for list_ in split:
    for word in list_:
        if word in values:
            for i in range(len(punctuations)):
                scores[i] += values[word]
        else:
            continue
```

And this was my second attempt:

```
count = [] 
scores = []

for list_ in split:
    for word in list_:
        if word in values:
            count.append(values[word])           
        else:
            continue
    scores.append(sum(count))
```

I've tried some other ways but I cannot find a solution, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at 'list comprehensions'? It's the Pythonic way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is actually a really clean language for writing solutions to these types of problems:

```
sentences = ['This is so awesome , fr!', 'Ngl Im bad', 'awesome ! still bad tho' ] 
values = {'awesome': 4, 'bad': -1}

ratings = [sum(values[word] if word in values else 0 for word in sentence.split()) for sentence in sentences]
print(ratings)
```

Result:

```
[4, -1, 3]
```

A bit of explanation:

- the whole expression assigned to `ratings` is a list comprehension, which constructs a list from an internal generator; a simple example is `x = [range(3)]`
- the generator loops over ever `sentence` in `sentences` and processes it
- the processing consists of computing the sum of the values from a second generator
- the second generator loops over the words in the `sentence`, by splitting it over spaces using `.split()` and looks up the value in `values` or assigns it value `0` if it's not in `values`

Perhaps a more readable version of the same code:

```
ratings = [
    sum(
        values[word] if word in values else 0 
        for word in sentence.split()
    ) 
    for sentence in sentences
]
```

Comment: `values[word] if word in values else 0` can be simplified to `values.get(word, 0)`

Comment: It's shorter, but I don't know if I agree that it's simpler. I don't think it's more efficient, as it adds a function call to a function that internally likely has very similar logic. And I like how the current solution reads like what it does.